# "NoPermissionsInAccessToken" when trying to get user profile photo using Microsoft Graph API + react-adal

Tags: reactjs, azure, adal

I'm trying to fetch the user's profile photo using `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value` endpoint and by following [these](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profilephoto-get?view=graph-rest-1.0) instructions. In our React app we're using `react-adal`, so I first got an access token using `adalGetToken(authContext, "https://graph.microsoft.com/")` and then made the call with

```
axios.get("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value", {
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
  },
})
```

However, the response is

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "NoPermissionsInAccessToken",
    "message": "The token contains no permissions, or permissions can not be understood.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "d2ed76f0-7f35-4014-bc53-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "date": "2020-05-29T09:27:12"
    }
  }
}
```

When I make a call to `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me` using the same token, I get a proper response, eg

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users/$entity",
  "id": "<id>",
  ...
}
```

In Azure Portal I have delegated `User.Read` permissions for the application: [Image of the permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTWMT.png)

What could be the problem?

Comment: As per documentation, GET /me/photo "This operation in version 1.0 supports only a user's work or school mailboxes and not personal mailboxes."

Comment: I'm using work account

Comment: According to the error, the issue is in token not from the graph API. Please check your token in [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms/). For API  you can check-in graph explorer.

Answer (score 1):

You are validating the token by calling a different endpoint locally (`v1.0/me`) than your app is calling (`v1.0/me/photo/$value`).

You can manually validate access tokens using tools like https://jwt.io/ and https://jwt.ms/

Per the comment by @sruthi-j-msft-identity, `v1.0/me/photo` is not available for personal accounts. Try using `beta/me/photo/$value` in your React app if you are working with personal accounts. ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profilephoto-get?view=graph-rest-beta#permissions

The beta API contains preview features and should not be used for production systems.

Comment: I know the endpoint is different. I just demonstrated that at least some endpoint works so my token must be valid for that at least. And I'm using a work account